# Problem with dynamically including CSS from within bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Im trying to build a bookmarklet (like http://erkie.github.com/). What i need to do is include a jsfile and in that jsfile i will include another jsfile and a CSS file.

I have the following in the bookmark:

```
javascript:var script = document.createElement('script');script.id='invoketest';script.type='text/javascript';script.src='http://mydomain.com/start.js';document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);void(0);
```

This will include my start.js file and this works just fine. Now my start.js file looks like this:

```
  var script2 = document.createElement('script');
  script2.type = 'text/javascript';
  script2.src = 'http://mydomain.com/someother.js';
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script2);

  var script1 = document.createElement('link');
  script1.rel = 'stylesheet';
  script1.type = 'text/css';
  script1.href = 'http://mydomain.com/someCSS.css';
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script1);
```

This kind of work, as the "someother.js" script is loaded just fine. But the "someCSS.css" is NOT loaded for some reason.

Im testing in chrome, but it does not work in IE and FF either.

Hope this makes sense

BR/Sune

Comment: Please include those scripts (bookmarklet and start.js) inside an anonymous wrapper function; now you're possibly overwriting `script`, `script1` and `script2` in the global namespace of a badly written script on the current page. BTW, do you get any error messages in the console? Do you see a new element being added to the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that adding

```
void(script1);
```

after the script1 block and same for script2 helped. Now the CSS is loaded just fine.

BR/Sune

Comment: that makes no sense, unless you were testing those two blocks with bookmarklets too